# I want to get Pop-up window for image in bootstrap and php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

This  is my code for image gallery through PHP and Bootstrap. It's Working Fine But I  want to get pop-up window for image when user click on that particular image. Is there any functionality i can add in this code?

Thanks in advance

```
<h3>Photo Gallery</h3>
<ul id="categories">
<li>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-filter=".resort" onClick="makeCall('Resort');" class="Resort active">1</a>
</li>
<li class="rooms">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-filter=".beach" onClick="makeCall('Rooms');" class="Rooms">2</a>
 </li>
<li>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-filter=".beach" onClick="makeCall('Dinning');" class="Dinning">3</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-filter=".beach" onClick="makeCall('Swiming-Pool');" class="Swiming-Pool">4</a>
 </li>
<li class="last">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-filter=".beach" onClick="makeCall('all');" class="all">View all</a>
</li>
</ul>

<div class="row gallery gallery-section" id="demoLightbox" class="lightbox hide fade"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class='lightbox-content'>
  <?php

  $path = 'images/gallery/'; // Create initial "Folders" array
  $filetype = '*.*';
  $_POST['type']='all';
  if($_POST['type']!='all')
  {
    $classloop[] = $_POST['type'];
    $folders[]=ucfirst($_POST['type']);
    $start=0;
    $foldercount = count($folders)-1;
  }
  else
  {
    if ($dir = opendir($path))
    {
        $j = 0;
        while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false)
        {
            if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && is_dir($path.$file))
            {
                $j++;
                $folders[$j] = $file;
            }
        }
    }
    $classloop = array("","","resort","envato");
    $start=1;
    $foldercount = count($folders);
 }

 for ($i = $start; $i <= $foldercount ; $i++)
 {
    $folderpath = $path.$folders[$i];
    $images = glob($folderpath."/".$filetype);
    $count = count($images);
    if($count>0)
    {
      for ($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++)
        { ?>
        <?php
          $z = $j%3;

          echo '<div class="'.$folders[$i].' photo-item hover test" style="float:left;">';

          echo '<a href="'.$images[$j].'" class="image-box">';

          echo '<div class="photo">';

          echo '<span class="text"><span class="anchor"></span></span>';

          echo '</div>';

          echo '<img src="'.$images[$j].'" alt=""  width="260"  height="170"/>';

          echo ' </a></div>';

          echo '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a href="#demoLightbox" class="gphoto" data-toggle="lightbox">';
          echo '<img src="images/delux.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />';
          echo '</a></div>';

        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<div align="center" style="width: 100%;">No image(s) found</div>';
    }
}
?>

</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Yes, there is functionality that you can add to your code.

Comment: @Epodax can you tell me which are those functionality ? or if possible u can give me code Thanx .

Comment: No, SO is not a free coding service and we are not here to recommend external resources as it's off-topic

Comment: @Epodax Thanx for Your valuable time. If can't help then don't waste other's time.

Comment: Don't waste other people's time by posting a off-topic question.

Comment: @Epodax It's stackoverflow and here generally people put their technical or coding query. And my question related to technical topic.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. - from the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91587/discussion-between-sagar-sadrani-and-epodax).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah..

Place this in css

```
 <style type="text/css">
    /* popup_box DIV-Styles*/
    #popup_box { 
        display:none; /* Hide the DIV */
        position:fixed;  
        _position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6 */  
        height:auto;  
        width:600px;  
        /*background:#FFFFFF;*/  
        left: 450px;
        top:63px;
        z-index:100; /* Layering ( on-top of others), if you have lots of layers: I just maximized, you can change it yourself */
        margin-left: 0px;  

        /* additional features, can be omitted */
        /*border:2px solid #ff0000; */
        padding:0px;  
        font-size:15px;  
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #FF3333;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #0033FF;
        box-shadow: 0 0 25px #990000;

    }

    a{  
        cursor: pointer;  
        text-decoration:none;  
    } 

    /* This is for the positioning of the Close Link */
    #popupBoxClose {
        font-size:20px;  
        line-height:15px;  
        right:5px;  
        top:5px;  
        position:absolute;  
        color:#6fa5e2;  
        font-weight:500;    
    }
</style>
```

make a div with above id

attach a javascript function on button click

To open pop up

```
<button type="button" class="open" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Open" onclick="return loadPopupBox();"><span aria-hidden="true">Open</span></button>
```

To close pop up

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onclick="return unloadPopupBox();"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
```

Write some javascript

```
function unloadPopupBox() {

    $('#yourdiv').hide();
}

function loadPopupBox(data) {   // To Load the Popupbox

        $('#yourdiv').show();
    });
```

Make sure you have hide the div on load of the page.

Comment: Thanx Its showing Pop for images but its showing all images instead of category-wise.

Comment: Yeah i did that as per my code but anyway i will figure it out. Thanx for your help it really worked (Y)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean modal that appears when clicked, **yes** there is, and what I have here is actually a [template](http://materializecss.com/media.html) you can use ( or not ) which you can play around.